# SPIP add GET variable to URL

Tags: url, get, spip

I'm using [SPIP](http://www.spip.net/) with files of my own that are included according to keywords. For example, adding the keyword `inc-bla` to an article makes that the file `.../squellettes/.../inc-bla.html` is included. In one of those files, I want to make a link to the current page with a GET variable added to the URL:

```
[(#ENV{date}|diffdays|<{40}|?{<a href="#URL_ARTICLE?date=[(#ENV{date}|next_sunday)]">Some text...</a>,''})]
```

Now the problem is that the question mark `?` is hard-coded, and sometimes the URL already has a question mark. So this code creates links like `...spip.php?article123?date=2014-03-30`, which should be `...spip.php?article123&date=2014-03-30`. I cannot hard-code an ampersand `&` because not every link has a question mark in it already.

Is there a way to add a GET variable to a URL in SPIP?

Comment: Your are looking for the filter |parametre_url : https://www.spip.net/en_article4983.html#parametre_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is using [filters](http://www.spip.net/en_article2465.html). We need to create our own filter, a PHP function like this:

```php
function url_add_get_var($url,$name,$value) {
    $name = urlencode($name);
    $value = urlencode($value);
    // If there is no question mark in the URL ...
    if (strpos($url,'?') === false) {
        // Add the variable with a question mark
        return "$url?$name=$value";
    } else {
        // If there is a question mark, add the variable with an ampersand
        return "$url&$name=$value";
    }
}
```

Now, we can use it in SPIP like this:

```
[(text|filter{var1,var2, ...})]
```

So, in this case:

```
[(#URL_ARTICLE|url_add_get_var{date,[(#ENV{date}|next_sunday)]})]
```

And the full code:

```
[(#ENV{date}|diffdays|<{40}|?{<a href="[(#URL_ARTICLE|url_add_get_var{date,[(#ENV{date}|next_sunday)]})]">Some text...</a>,''})]
```

Comment: |parametrre_url is doing it, nativly.